# ggplot: Y-axis as count of specific value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a bar chart of how many training courses my employees have completed. To do this, I have a data frame called `iud`, where each row is a distinct course they have begun taking:

```
  name percent
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 Nardo   41.7 
2 Nardo    0   
3 Nardo    4.59
4 Nardo  100
...
```

I am trying to use ggplot to create a bar chartwhere the y axis is a count of the number of instances where `percent` is equal to 100. (So for the data above, Nardo's bar would be at 1). I am currently using this:

```
cpu <- ggplot(iud, aes(name)) + 
  geom_bar(data=subset(iud,percent=="100"), stat = "count") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,15,1))
```

The chart looks correct, but it does not include bars where the count of `percent` equals 0 (Employees who have begun, but not completed a course, are not included on the chart).

Is there a better way I can be doing this to make sure that all employees are charted--including one's where the y-axis values would be 0?

Comment: What should a barplot of 0 show?

Comment: Well there wouldn't be a bar for that column, there would at least be a space for where that bar would be. Most other names on the on the x-axis do not equal 0. It would be nice to see them all together rather than having those columns disappear altogether.

Comment: The top of the help page for `?geom_bar` explained that it is `geom_col` that should be used if you don't want counts. I would argue that geom_bar is poorly named.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is easiest to pre-process the data, to count the number of 100%  first.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(name) %>% 
  summarise(n = sum(percent == 100)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = n)) +
  geom_col()

#data
library(readr)
df <- read_delim("name percent
Nardo 41.7
Nardo 0
Nardo 4.59
Nardo 100
Ardi 45", delim = " ")
```